# Updating UIViewController in right way in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am using a UIViewController as a View for SwiftUI and I want update it, I personally came to this down code for update, but as i see this code I feel that I am repeating codes or maybe there is more better way for update, I would like pros take a look at it and correct my way, thanks.

```
struct UIViewControllerRepresentableView: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    
    let viewColor: UIColor
    
    func makeUIViewController(context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<UIViewControllerRepresentableView>) -> UIViewControllerModel {
        
        return UIViewControllerModel(viewColor: viewColor)
        
    }
    
    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: UIViewControllerModel, context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<UIViewControllerRepresentableView>) {
        
        let customUIView = UIView()
        customUIView.backgroundColor = viewColor
        
        uiViewController.view.addSubview(customUIView)
        customUIView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        customUIView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100).isActive = true
        customUIView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100).isActive = true
        customUIView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: uiViewController.view.centerXAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        customUIView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: uiViewController.view.centerYAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        
    }
    
    class UIViewControllerModel: UIViewController {
        
        var viewColor: UIColor
        
        init(viewColor: UIColor) {
            self.viewColor = viewColor
            super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
        }
        
        required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
            fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
        }
        
        override func loadView() {
            
            view = UIView()
            
            let customUIView = UIView()
            customUIView.backgroundColor = viewColor
            
            view.addSubview(customUIView)
            customUIView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            customUIView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100).isActive = true
            customUIView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100).isActive = true
            customUIView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
            customUIView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
            
        }
        
    }
    
}
```

---

use case:

```
import SwiftUI
    
    struct ContentView: View {
        
        @State private var viewColor: UIColor = UIColor.purple
        
        var body: some View {
    
            UIViewControllerRepresentableView(viewColor: viewColor)
                .background(Color.gray)
                .frame(width: 200, height: 200, alignment: .center)
                .cornerRadius(10)
            
            Button("update") { viewColor = UIColor.orange }
    
        }
    }
```

[image]

---

**UPDATE:**

```
struct UIViewControllerRepresentableView: UIViewControllerRepresentable {

    let viewColor: UIColor
    let viewSize: CGSize

    func makeUIViewController(context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<UIViewControllerRepresentableView>) -> UIViewControllerModel {

        return UIViewControllerModel(viewColor: viewColor, viewSize: viewSize)
  
    }

    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: UIViewControllerModel, context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<UIViewControllerRepresentableView>) {

        uiViewController.view.addSubview(uiViewController.UIViewBuilderFunction(backgroundView: uiViewController.view, viewColor: viewColor, viewSize: viewSize))

    }

    
    class UIViewControllerModel: UIViewController {

        var viewColor: UIColor
        var viewSize: CGSize

        let customUIView: UIView = UIView()

        init(viewColor: UIColor, viewSize: CGSize) {
            self.viewColor = viewColor
            self.viewSize = viewSize
            super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
        }

        required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
            fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
        }

        override func loadView() {

            view = UIView()

            view.addSubview(UIViewBuilderFunction(backgroundView: view, viewColor: viewColor, viewSize: viewSize))
 
        }

        func UIViewBuilderFunction(backgroundView: UIView, viewColor: UIColor, viewSize: CGSize) -> UIView {

            customUIView.removeConstraints(customUIView.constraints)
            customUIView.removeFromSuperview()

            customUIView.backgroundColor = viewColor

            backgroundView.addSubview(customUIView)
             
            customUIView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            customUIView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: viewSize.width).isActive = true
            customUIView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: viewSize.height).isActive = true
            customUIView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: backgroundView.centerXAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
            customUIView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: backgroundView.centerYAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true

            return customUIView
 
        }

    }
  
}
```

---

use case:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var viewColor: UIColor = UIColor.purple
    @State private var viewSize: CGSize = CGSize(width: 100, height: 100)
    
    var body: some View {

        UIViewControllerRepresentableView(viewColor: viewColor, viewSize: viewSize)
            .background(Color.gray)
            .frame(width: 200, height: 200, alignment: .center)
            .cornerRadius(10)
        
        Button("update color") { viewColor = UIColor.orange }.padding()
        
        Button("update size") { viewSize = CGSize(width: 50, height: 50) }.padding()

    }
}
```

---

update 2:

```
    var viewColor: UIColor {
    
    didSet(oldValue) {

        if oldValue != viewColor {
            updateCustomViewColor()
        }

    }
    
}

var viewSize: CGSize {

    didSet(oldValue) {

        if oldValue != viewSize {
            updateCustomViewSizeConstraints()
        }
    }

}
```

---

```
override func loadView() {
    view = UIView()
    setupView()
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your current code you are creating new `UIView` on every update of `UIViewController` and putting it on top of already existing views, you are not just changing the colour of your custom `UIView`.

---

You could do something like this instead:

```
struct UIViewControllerRepresentableView: UIViewControllerRepresentable {

    let viewColor: UIColor
    let viewSize: CGSize

    func makeUIViewController(context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<UIViewControllerRepresentableView>) -> UIViewControllerModel {
        UIViewControllerModel(viewColor: viewColor, viewSize: viewSize)
    }

    func updateUIViewController(_ controller: UIViewControllerModel, context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<UIViewControllerRepresentableView>) {
        controller.viewColor = viewColor
        controller.viewSize = viewSize
    }
}

class UIViewControllerModel: UIViewController {

    var viewColor: UIColor {
        didSet {
            updateCustomViewColor()
        }
    }

    var viewSize: CGSize {
        didSet {
            updateCustomViewSizeConstraints()
        }
    }

    private var customView: UIView!
    private var customViewHeightAnchor: NSLayoutConstraint!
    private var customViewWidthAnchor: NSLayoutConstraint!

    init(viewColor: UIColor, viewSize: CGSize) {
        self.viewColor = viewColor
        self.viewSize = viewSize
        super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.setupView()
    }

    private func setupView() {
        customView = UIView()
        customView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        customView.backgroundColor = viewColor

        view.addSubview(customView)

        customViewHeightAnchor = customView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: viewSize.height)
        customViewWidthAnchor = customView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: viewSize.width)

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            customViewHeightAnchor,
            customViewWidthAnchor,
            customView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor, constant: 0),
            customView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor, constant: 0)
        ])
    }

    private func updateCustomViewColor() {
        customView.backgroundColor = viewColor
    }

    private func updateCustomViewSizeConstraints() {
        customViewHeightAnchor.constant = viewSize.height
        customViewWidthAnchor.constant = viewSize.width
    }
}
```

---

By implementing your `UIViewControllerRepresentableView` this way, whenever SwiftUI updates your `UIViewController` *viewColor* property is set to a new value and *didSet* is getting called, which update *customView* `backgroundColor`.

Comment: After I post my question and before you answering me I tested my codes in deferent situation and I found by myself that I am not updating the View but rendering over existing View! So nice you mentioned about that! if you interested I can show another way of updating the View but in very special and decent way, and maybe you can see this code as well for an improvement or update?

Comment: @swiftPunk Sure, go ahead, I did not think about any improvements, just made small changes to your code to make it work correctly.

Comment: thanks, I am going post my new version corrected code as update, your way of updating the View is through **didSet**, which I think it is a very clever way, I update with direct function, let me show you in up. I like to know which way is better and know about pros and cons, I am all here to learning.

Comment: @swiftPunk I just looked at your update, I can say one thing: you are overcomplicating this by quite a bit. The goal is to update the existing view, to update it you do not need to remove it and then re-add it, just update the required properties.

Comment: yes, but for updating the size, i guess, we have to remove all thing then add new one, am I wrong?

Comment: @swiftPunk No, you do not need to remove the view to update its size. Just update the constraints. I updated my answer.

Comment: @swiftPunk Updated the answer. You could even do it differently by saving height/width constraints as local UIViewController properties and changing the constant only instead of changing the value like I did now.

Comment: I checked your code, I got 2 issue with them, first important one, have you seen the counsel complaining massage? you are updating constraint but the old one already exist, second one, you just forgot initializing **viewSize** in **UIViewControllerModel**

Comment: @swiftPunk I'm coding this without using Xcode :D pardon, for forgetting something. Let me spin up my IDE real quick.

Comment: thanks, as I see you you are using **viewDidLoad()** I was using also, but I learned It is better use **loadView()** also I made an update to your **didSet**, I like to know your opinion about those, the code is in up

Comment: @swiftPunk That looks fine. You do not need to check oldValue != newValue, because SwiftUI is smart enough: it does not call update on the view if same values have been passed. Of course it does try to update the colour as well when the size changes and vice verse, but it does not really matter.

Comment: It was pleaser to learning from you, thanks again for your explaining and time