# How to pass data from SwiftUI to ViewController

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

hoping someone can help me with this, I am building an iOS app with Swift and SwiftUI that launches different Unity scenes with the click of different buttons. I have the Unity part working well thanks to some good tutorials but I am having trouble being able to change scene with different button clicks. The tutorials I have followed set up the Unity code in a view controller that is then launched from a navigation view. I can launch the view controller and change the sceneNumber to whichever one I want and it will load that scene. I can't find away to do that in a way that is set before I launch the view controller.

Here is my View where the LauncherView has two buttons that will launch the view controller, I would like to change which sceneNumber is sent to the ViewController. I also have the problem of when I go back in the app and click through again nothing is displaying. I think this is because the UnityBridge class is already created and in the background somewhere.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks.

Here is my view code:

```
var sceneNumber: String = ""
    
    struct MyViewController: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    
      func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> UIViewController {
       
        let vc = UIViewController()
       
        UnityBridge.getInstance().onReady = {
            print("Unity is now ready!")
            UnityBridge.getInstance().show(controller: vc)
            let api = UnityBridge.getInstance().api
            api.test(sceneNumber) 
        }
        
        return vc
      }
    
      func updateUIViewController(_ viewController: UIViewController, context: Context) {}
    }
    
    struct ContentView: View {
        
        var body: some View {
            
            VStack{
                MyViewController()
            }
        }
    }
    
    struct FirstView: View {
        var body: some View {
            NavigationView{
                VStack{
                    NavigationLink(destination: ContentView()) { //+ code to set sceneNumber to "1"
                        Text("Launch Unity Scene 1")
                    }
                    Text("")
                    NavigationLink(destination: ContentView()) { //+code to set sceneNumber to "2"
                        Text("Launch Unity Scene 2")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

And here is the UnityBridge class code:

```
import Foundation
import UnityFramework
import SwiftUI

class API: NativeCallsProtocol {

    internal weak var bridge: UnityBridge!
    
    /**
        Function pointers to static functions declared in Unity
     */
    
    private var testCallback: TestDelegate!
    
    /**
        Public API
     */
    
    public func test(_ value: String) {
        self.testCallback(value)
    }
    
    /**
        Internal methods are called by Unity
     */
    
    internal func onUnityStateChange(_ state: String) {
        switch (state) {
        case "ready":
            self.bridge.unityGotReady()
        default:
            return
        }
    }
    
    internal func onSetTestDelegate(_ delegate: TestDelegate!) {
        self.testCallback = delegate
    }
    
}

class UnityBridge: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, UnityFrameworkListener {
 
    private static var instance : UnityBridge?
    
    internal(set) public var isReady: Bool = false
    public var api: API
    private let ufw: UnityFramework
    
    public var view: UIView? {
        get { return self.ufw.appController()?.rootView }
    }
    public var onReady: () -> () = {}
    
    public static func getInstance() -> UnityBridge {
        print("Hello1.1")
        //UnityBridge.instance?.unload()
        
        if UnityBridge.instance == nil {
            print("Hello1.2")
            UnityBridge.instance = UnityBridge()
            
        }
        print("Hello1.3")
        return UnityBridge.instance!
        
    }
    
    private static func loadUnityFramework() -> UnityFramework? {
        print("Hello2")
        let bundlePath: String = Bundle.main.bundlePath + "/Frameworks/UnityFramework.framework"
        let bundle = Bundle(path: bundlePath)
        if bundle?.isLoaded == false {
            bundle?.load()
        }
   
        let ufw = bundle?.principalClass?.getInstance()
        if ufw?.appController() == nil {
            let machineHeader = UnsafeMutablePointer<MachHeader>.allocate(capacity: 1)
            machineHeader.pointee = _mh_execute_header
            ufw!.setExecuteHeader(machineHeader)
        }
        return ufw
    }
    
    internal override init() {
        print("Hello3")

        self.ufw = UnityBridge.loadUnityFramework()!
        self.ufw.setDataBundleId("com.unity3d.framework")
        self.api = API()
        super.init()
        self.api.bridge = self
        self.ufw.register(self)
        FrameworkLibAPI.registerAPIforNativeCalls(self.api)
   
        ufw.runEmbedded(withArgc: CommandLine.argc, argv: CommandLine.unsafeArgv, appLaunchOpts: nil)
    }
    
    public func show(controller: UIViewController) {
        print("Hello4")
        if self.isReady {
            self.ufw.showUnityWindow()
        }
        if let view = self.view {
            controller.view?.addSubview(view)
        }
        
    }

    public func unload() {
        print("Hello5")
        self.ufw.unloadApplication()
    }
    
    internal func unityGotReady() {
        print("Hello6")
        self.isReady = true
        onReady()
    }
    
    internal func unityDidUnload(_ notification: Notification!) {
        print("Hello7")
        ufw.unregisterFrameworkListener(self)
        UnityBridge.instance = nil
    }
 
}
```

Comment: I think this Link will answer you. https://stackoverflow.com/q/66183802/14998134

Comment: Look into implementing a Coordinator for your UIViewControllerRepresentable. Good example here: https://www.hackingwithswift.com/articles/175/advanced-coordinator-pattern-tutorial-ios

Comment: @swiftPunk thanks for your reply, I tried both your suggestions but unfortunately I can't make any headway, I just don't have the understanding/skill to go any further!